# How to plot multivariate tabular data

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have tabular data usual for numeric packages:

```
T = Table[{x, Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}];
T // TableForm
```

Now I want to plot `T`. I want to plot it discrete as two point plots against single `x`. How can I do that?

I can't catch how to use some of `ListPlot`s here.

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Transpose[Rest /@ T], DataRange -> T[[ {1, -1}, 1]]]` ?

Comment: Or `ListPlot[..., Filling -> Bottom]` if you want the `DiscretePlot` style

Comment: @Kuba isb't there some simpler function ready made?

Comment: @SuzanCioc One can not expect that there will be sparate function for each data structure you can imagine :)

Comment: This structure was imagined not by me, but by numerous creators of numeric packages, like Excel, Matlab, Statistica etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListPlot[{T[[All, {1, 2}]], T[[All, {1, 3}]]}]
```

or

```
ListPlot[T[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3}]
```

[image: plot screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ways:

```
pd = Map[Function[x, Thread[{#1, x}]], {##2}] & @@ Transpose[tab];
ListPlot[pd]
```

or

```
ListPlot[Transpose /@ ({{#1, #2}, {#1, #3}} & @@ Transpose[tab])]
```

As comments note you can also use:

```
DiscretePlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```